# Sending keyboard typed data to Webpage using flask SSE

Tags: python, linux, flask, gevent, monkeypatching

I am trying to send Keyboard typed data to a webpage using Flask SSE [following this tutorial](https://medium.com/code-zen/python-generator-and-html-server-sent-events-3cdf14140e56). I could send the data. But the problem is that I could send the data only when the cursor is focused on the terminal (I am using `input()` method in an infinite loop to capture data).

Since I want to capture data even though the cursor is not focused in the terminal I tried using the [keyboard module](https://pypi.org/project/keyboard/) (`record()` method). Though I could successfully run and capture in a separate program, I couldnt run it in Flask code. I am running the following code.

```
import gevent
from gevent.pywsgi import WSGIServer
from gevent import monkey
monkey.patch_all()
from numpy import random
from flask import Flask, json, Response, render_template
import keyboard
import sys


app = Flask(__name__)

def event():
    while True:
        print("Inside")
        recorded_events =  keyboard.read_key(suppress=True);

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/stream/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def stream():
    return Response(event(), mimetype="text/event-stream")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    WSGIServer(('', 5001), app).serve_forever()
```

Comment: I tried your code on my mac in VSCode. After giving enough permissions, my keystrokes were triggered no matter where I was. On the terminal, VScode, on browser, everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Aren't you supposed to yield the values?

```
def event():
    while True:
        yield keyboard.read_key(suppress=True)
```